# How to look up objects in Django model has ManyToMany relations

Tags: django

I had posted about same issue. But I cannot acquire what I want to know. So, I post again.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = model.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = TextField()
    tags = ManyToManyField(‘Tag’,blank=True)
    …

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ChatField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    …
```

I try to find a simple way to find blogs has same tags.
For example, a certain blog has tag “1”, “2”, “3”. I want to find some blogs which has at least one of the tags.
There are objects like these:

```
Blog A Object has tag [“1”, ”2”, ”3”]
Blog B Object has tag [“1”, “3”]
Blog C Object has tag [“2”, “3”]
Blog D Object has tag [“1”, “2”]
Blog E Object has tag [“3”, ”4”, ”5”]
Blog F Object has tag [“6”, ”7”, ”8”]
```

In this situation. I want to find Blogs has at least one of the Blog A’s tag [“1”,”2”,”3”]

So the result have to be [A,B,C,D,E]

I think, below is not a solution.

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(tags__tag='1').filter(tags__tag='2').filter(tags_tag='f3')
```

Or

```
blogs = Blog.object.filter(tags__tag='1')
blogs = blogs.filter(tags__tag='2')
blogs = blogs.filter(tags__tag='3')
```

because it may be make [Blog A] as the result.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
blogs = Blog.object.filter(tags__tag__in=['1', '2', '3'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have blog with title 'a' and you want to find blogs similar to blog 'a'

```
b = Blog.objects.get(title='a')
b_tags = b.tags.all()
similar_blogs = Blog.objects.filter(tags__in=b_tags)
```

Comment: similar_blogs = Blog.objecrs.filter(tags__in=b_tags).distinct().exclude(title='a')